# Start Activity once selected Caldroid date cell

Tags: java, android

I ran into a strange problem whilst developing my android application. I implemented caldroid (a popular 3rd party calendar), When a user selects a date it should pass this information to a new activity and then start it. The information is correctly formatted but the activity fails to start. The following error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MySchedule{4271d8a8} not attached to Activity
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:878)
            at salespharma.sptouchexpress.modules.salescalls.MySchedule.mySchedule(MySchedule.java:149)
            at salespharma.sptouchexpress.modules.salescalls.MySchedule$2.onLongClickDate(MySchedule.java:131)
            at com.roomorama.caldroid.CaldroidFragment$2.onItemLongClick(CaldroidFragment.java:895)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:2979)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:2928)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The activity launches fine outside of this method:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        CaldroidFragment caldroidFragment = new CaldroidFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
        args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        caldroidFragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, caldroidFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        final CaldroidListener listener = new CaldroidListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {

                 month = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MM", date); //06
                year = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy", date); //2013
                 day = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd", date); //20

                Log.d("Given_Date", month + "/" +day  + "/" + year);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChangeMonth(int month, int year) {
            //    String text = "month: " + month + " year: " + year;

            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClickDate(Date date, View view) {
                month = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MM", date); //06
                year = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy", date); //2013
                day = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd", date); //20
                mySchedule();
//Activity opens up fine outside of this method.
            }

            @Override
            public void onCaldroidViewCreated() {

            }

        };

        caldroidFragment.setCaldroidListener(listener);

    }

public void mySchedule() {
    Intent in = new Intent(context, MySalesCalls.class);
    in.putExtra("Given_Date", month + "/" +day  + "/" + year);
    startActivity(in);

}
```

I have no idea why it's throwing this error as I always start my activities using this method.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you should do this stuff in `onViewCreated()` instead of `onActivityCreated()`.

Comment: I moved my methods over to onViewCreated, I still get the same error. What else could be causing this error? (I am using support fragment if that has any effect)